# Can't align content to have matching left and right spacing between container

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

The fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/UzSt8/

I seem to have a smaller space to the left, vs the one on the right. I'd like a even spacing on both left and right.

Not sure where to change this.

Please note this is created using foundation 4 css etc

THanks

```
               </div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
          <div class="panel">

            <style>
              .slider { height: 180px; float:center;}
          </style>
          <ul class="large-block-grid-4 small-block-grid-2">
            <li><span class="label">HIGH</span><div class="slider"></div><span class="success label">LOW</span>
            <li><span class="label">HIGH</span><div class="slider"></div><span class="success label">LOW</span>
            <li><span class="label">HIGH</span><div class="slider"></div><span class="success label">LOW</span>
            <li><span class="label">HIGH</span><div class="slider"></div><span class="success label">LOW</span>
              </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Could you please specify on left side of what and on right side of what? :)

Comment: The green and red boxs I want to align so they are equal spaces on the left and right side on the outside container

Answer (score 0):

your question is still ambiguous, but is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/f2kK6/

Had to clean some things up

```
<div style="float:left;">
     <ul style="list-style:none;margin-left:-40px;">
     <li><span class="label">HIGH</span><div class="slider"></div></li>
     <li><span class="success label">LOW</span></li>
     <li style="margin-top:15px;"><span class="label">HIGH</span><div class="slider"></div></li>
     <li><span class="success label">LOW</span></li>
     </ul>
              </div>
      <div style="float:right;">
     <ul style="list-style:none;margin-left:-40px;">
     <li><span class="label">HIGH</span><div class="slider"></div></li>
     <li><span class="success label">LOW</span></li>
     <li style="margin-top:15px;"><span class="label">HIGH</span><div class="slider"></div></li>
     <li><span class="success label">LOW</span></li>
     </ul>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`float: center` does not exist
Use margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; and give your container a specific width